# Re-populate Image "Usage" references in Wagtail Admin?

Tags: wagtail, wagtail-admin

[Image usage field](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XrOy2.png)

Hi, I recently upgraded Wagtail from v2 to v4 and noticed they added a new metafield called image usage in Wagtail Admin. But the issue is that all images referenced before the upgrade say they are used 0 times. It seems like the db table is empty as well. Is there any way to re-populate them?

As far as I know, [the docs on the image field](https://docs.wagtail.org/en/v4.2.3/advanced_topics/images/index.html) doesn't go over this feature. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [Wagtail 4.1 release notes about this feature](https://docs.wagtail.org/en/stable/releases/4.1.html#rebuild-references-index-management-command):

> After upgrading, you will need to run `./manage.py rebuild_references_index` in order to populate the references table and ensure that usage counts for images, documents and snippets are displayed accurately.